# javascript page is loading earlier than html page and showing null value

Tags: javascript

I am creating a invoice software in html, css, and javascript. I fetched  with document.getElementById(), but in console is showing null value I searched a lot on internet i found that js file is loading earlier than my html file. Please tell solution.

I tried many times but did not succeed

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Probably it's [this often-reported issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an external script, use the [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attributes) attribute:

```
<script src="some_script.js" defer><script>
```

If you're using an inline script, use [type=module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type):

```
<script type="module">
    x = document.getElementById("your_id");
    console.log(x);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try it by giving it between the body and the html closing tag so that your html file loads first then the js file.